# Can't run asammdf GUI after installing

Tags: python, installation, asammdf

I used pip to install the asammdf library. When i want to run the GUI, i following error message:

Full error message from the console:

```
<class 'TypeError'>  
arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  setStyle(a0: Optional[QStyle]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QCommonStyle'
  setStyle(a0: Optional[str]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QCommonStyle'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\sporrcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\asammdf.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sporrcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\asammdf\gui\asammdfgui.py", line 45, in main
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
```

Can anyone tell me, what i am missing to be able to start the GUI and use it?

Thanks a lot!!

I installed the missing py libraries already, which i have seen from the console.

Comment: make sure you have pyside 6.3.1 installed

Comment: the weired thing is, if i run the asammdfgui.py file directly, the GUI works fine - without error message.

but if i try to run the asammdf exe file from the cmd windows, i get the above error message. i installed the pyside 6.3.1

Comment: Do u have any other idea for me? Thx a lot!!!

Comment: If I were to bet I would say that you have multiple python environments/installs and the exe is executed from the one that has the incompatible pyside version